# Does Capitalization of Integers Matter for Buffer Writing?

Tags: java, networking

Good day,

I'm working on a server emulator, sending OPCode data to the client.

I'm just curious if the formatting with regards to Capitalization matters when using Integers such as:

0xfe vs 0xFE or 0x01 vs just 1

Any help would be appreciated, that way I can keep a better consistent format.

Cheers

Comment: That entirely depends on the code that processes the strings at the other end.  In general, Java routines process hex case-blind, and I'd regard as defective any code which did not do so, but if there's a way to do it wrong, someone somewhere will do it that way.  I'm less opinionated with respect to mixing hex and decimal representation; I'd advise consistency.

Comment: Are you actually sending hex strings or just using hex as a way of sending a value?  E.g. `write(0xf), write(0x0f), write(15), write(0b1111), write(0xF), etc` would all go an output channel the same way assuming write expects to write a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may be confusing presentation format with intrinsic value. Output formats are typically decimal but they can be any radix one chooses (or can actually represent a character depending on its interpretation). All of these ways of specifying a byte value have the same intrinsic value of decimal 15. They are interpreted at compile time and stored in memory (or a class file) the same way.

```
for (byte b : new byte[] {0xF, 0xf, 0x0f, 0x0F, 0b1111, 017, 15}) {
    byte ret = write(b);
    System.out.println("Returned: " + ret);
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
Received: 15
Returned: 15

Received: 15
Returned: 15

Received: 15
Returned: 15

Received: 15
Returned: 15

Received: 15
Returned: 15
```

This method simply receives a byte value, prints it and returns the same byte.

```
public static byte write(byte v) {
    System.out.println("Received: " + v);
    return v;
}
```